# numerical sorting but keeping duplicates

Tags: bash, macos, sorting, tr, numerical

I'm sorting a file numerically with almost nine hundred lines. For others the commands

```
tr '\r' '\n' < myfile.txt | sort
```

or

```
tr '\r' '\n' < myfile.txt | sort -n
```

seems to do the trick, but for me, I don't get the output I want (only two hundred lines). I can see that all duplicate numbers are lost on my mac, and I get the terminal error "tr: illegal byte sequence".

What am I doing wrong, and why can't I figure out how to save the file? Can it have something to with the file having blank columns?

The file is here:
dropbox.com/s/umzx64c5ix90l3y/Proteins.txt?dl=0

EDIT/CLARIFICATION:

When I've sorted all the lines numerically, I need to combinde the lines with identical number in a way so that new information is added to the upper line. Take for instance the lines with no 61:

```
Col   1     2      3     4       5       6         7         8      9   10    11
     61 PTS...  cyt   1bl..   0,38  MONOMER homo-trimer FRUC... PER...Bac..
     61 PTS...                                                                 3
```

becomes:

```
Col   1     2      3     4       5       6         7         8      9   10    11
     61 PTS...  cyt   1bl..   0,38  MONOMER homo-trimer FRUC... PER...Bac..   3
```

If there are info in both lines that overlap, I need the information from the upper line to be kept.

Thanks :)

Comment: I tried it on Linux, Fedora 24, and I get 1021 lines of output.

Comment: That line number sounds right. Doesn't work on my mac...

Comment: @Ditte, do you care which line is the "upper" line? I'm afraid preceding numeric sorting may change order of lines with same number in arbitrary way compared to their order in original file.

Comment: @mike.dld I'm afraid I do :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is not properly UTF-8-encoded, while your locale is most certainly set to UTF-8. Line 195 contains (invalid sequences are marked with `<HEX>`):

```
1945    comM    protection against fracitins/bacteriocins (found by comparison to spr genome according to H<CE>varstein 2006)   integral membrane protein (H<CE>varstein)   no model
```

Figure out what the encoding is and then either convert the file to proper encoding or change the locale to accomodate. Simply trying

```
env LC_ALL=C tr '\r' '\n' < Proteins.txt | sort -n
```

seems to work for me, giving 1021 lines.

Comment: I can get this to work! Thanks! any clue how I do the combination of lines?

Comment: Hmm, you'll need to revise the question as right now it's not clear how the lines should be combined. E.g. in your data file there're 2 lines starting with number "2", which have different values in various columns: "dnaA" vs. "dnaN", "DNA_polymerase_III_beta_subunit" vs. "DNA polymerase III, beta subunit, sliding clamp". There's no simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on MAC. I reproduced the problem `illegal byte sequence` from tr and from sed.  It is the locale set on OS X, or rather I should say "not set".  Type in the `locale` command and you will see what I mean.  These are set in the Terminal app settings, or you can do it yourself.

The default locale for many applications can be `C`, or `POSIX`, basically that is ASCII.

So I did this:

```
LC_ALL=C tr '\r' '\n' < myfile.txt | sort -n
```

and that seemed OK.

You might wish to add :

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

to your `.bash_profile` rather than change your Terminal settings.

Comment: Setting `LC_ALL=C` globally is dubious advice; it will turn off useful functionality in many places.  It is a great workaround for handling incorrect encodings, but most of the time, you *want* UTF-8 to work on a modern system.